# Cascade master-detail and loaded record in knockout. js

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, master-detail

We have the following scenario:

```
One select conected to one observable property Countries, and countryId
Another child select conected to StateProvinces and stateProvinceId observable property 
A compute generating the dependency between the first and second property (Countris and StateProvinces).
We click Load and simulate load a entity from the server, and update the selected values: countryId and stateProvinceId. The real coding uses the mapping plugin.
```

Just to be more clear, see the working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sPTHm code, and click on "Load".

We start to have trouble when we simulate a async ajax request of the state/province select, in the line 48. When this request is async, the load does not works, just because the stateProvinceId is setted before the StateProvinces is loaded, and it will be reseted to null. See a simulation with a async request of StateProvinces here: http://jsfiddle.net/sPTHm/1/, and click on "Load".

We already try: throttle, computed observable recipe, deferEvaluation and a lot of search. What is the ideal recipe to this in knockoutjs?

Answer (score 0):

I would try chaining your ajax requests using the [jQuery deferred concept](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

```
        return $.when(self.dataSource.getRtuUserData(rtuId))
            .then(function (rtuUserData)
            {
                self.RtuUserData = ko.mapping.fromJS(rtuUserData);
                return self.dataSource.getRtuStatus(rtuId);
            })
            .then(function (rtuStatus)
            {
                self.RtuStatus = ko.mapping.fromJS(rtuStatus);
                return self.dataSource.getRtuLocation(rtuId);
            })
```

Each method on the dateSource object is wrapping an ajax call:

```
self.getRtuLinks = function (rtuId)
{
    return $.ajax(
    {
        url: urlRoot + '/rtus/' + rtuId + '/links',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        type: 'GET'
    });
}
```

In this way, you can load your two sets of data synchronously, which should solve your problem.

Comment: I understand, but, in this way, i just cannot load a entire and complex graph, update that in view model

Comment: I understand you suggestion, but I still have the load point, independent of the compute call. So, when i update the primitive values of view model, in load, the delay until the detail complete, will reset provinceStateId, consequence of data-bind value in select.